# HG reviewboard installation on Win7 x64

Tags: python, apache, mercurial, mod-wsgi, review-board

While it was stated that it's not the best idea to host a reviewboard for mercurial on windows evironment I stil gave it a try. So far I have not succeeded. And thus I am in search of help.

I am running Windows 7 x64 and have followed the official [Installing on Windows](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/installation/windows/) guide.

Here I had no problems, problem occured when I chose wsgi. Now I am using Apache 2.2 32bit, python 2.5.4 32 bit and I have downloaded an apache wsgi module from: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows

Strangly enough they don't have module for this particular combo (Apache 2.2|python 2.5) so I grabbed the closest thing: mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py26-3.3.so - Apache 2.2 / Python 2.6

Still I did not consider win32 would be of any problems for win64 huh ?

Well after I have told Apache2.2 in it's httpd.conf to "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so" that I have put in modules folder, here is what it told me:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of G:/tools/Apache2/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load G:/tools/Apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: %1 is not 
a valid Win32 application.
```

Is this cause I use python 2.5 not 2.6 AND/OR windows 7 64 ? And if it's has any relation to python version - I couldn't find wsgi mod for 2.5 at least not downloadable version, only sources that need to be compiled and then some.

Has anyone faced similar problems and could advice or give hint how to load those that wsgi module ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that mod_wsgi has to be compiled against the correct Python version, so you can't use mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py26-3.3.so with 2.5.4.

(BTW, not sure why you're still using 2.5 anyway?)

Comment: 2.5 python came with the manual on how to setup review board, well I guess they did not update installation guide. But this problem is resolved now - I installed reviewboard on linux environment, it was comfortable with python 2.7 and apache2 had wsgi by default. Thanks for comments though

Comment: @Xeperis: If you have your problem resolved, please add your own answer and accept it. Consider people visiting Stack Overflow: how this (unanswered at the moment) question will help them with their problems?